# How to correctly center-align the contents of two adjacent box split in a 2:1 ratio

Tags: html, css

My use case is the following:

I've got a center-aligned layout with a max-width of say 360px.

Part of that layout is a container with two adjacent boxes. The right one contains an image that fills 33% width of the *window*. Left to it should be a text container. This text container should be aligned with the left border of the remaining center-aligned layout.

Here's a sketch of it:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.items-end {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.items-start {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.top {
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato
}

.width-2-3 {
  width: 66.666%;
}

.width-1-3 {
  width: 33.3333%
}

.left-content,
.right-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.left-content {
  max-width: 240px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}

.right-content {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="col items-center">
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="width-2-3 col items-end">
    <div class="left-content">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-1-3 col items-start">
    <div class="right-content">[img]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically my goal is to left align those two rows, no matter how big the window width. But after trying for some time I just can't get the math right! So any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you want to align only the text container with the top one? or the image need to follow the text container

Comment: would you consider using flex box or css grids?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, the text container should basically stretch from the left of the top container right to the start of the image.

Comment: @CallumLinington flex would be fine, css grids probably not. I need to support IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @temani-afif I came up with a solution that required only one line to change

```
- max-width: calc(240px);
+ max-width: calc(180px + 25%);
```

This way the text container is always left aligned to the top container while taking all the available space until the 33% window-width image container starts. And this works for all window sizes. Thanks for your help everyone! :)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.items-end {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.items-start {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.top {
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato
}

.width-2-3 {
  width: 66.666%;
}

.width-1-3 {
  width: 33.3333%
}

.left-content,
.right-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.left-content {
  max-width: calc(180px + 25%);
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}

.right-content {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="col items-center">
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="width-2-3 col items-end">
    <div class="left-content">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-1-3 col items-start">
    <div class="right-content">[img]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it was easier than what I expected then :) to be more accurate the formula is exactly `calc( (360px + (3/2*100%)/3)/2)` where `3/2` is because the width was `2/3` and `1/3` is the width of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider negative margin left:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin:0;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.top {
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato
}

.width-2-3 {
  width: 66.666%;
}

.width-1-3 {
  width: 33.3333%
}

.left-content,
.right-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.left-content {
  max-width: 240px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}

.right-content {
  background: pink;
}

@media (min-width:360px) {
.left-content {
  margin-left:calc((150% - 360px)/2); /* 150 is 3/2*100% since the width is 2/3*/
}

.right-content {
  margin-left:calc(240px + ((200% - 360px)/2) - 150%); /*200% is equal to 150% of the left element */
}

}
```

```html
<div class="col items-center">
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="width-2-3 col">
    <div class="left-content">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="width-1-3 col">
    <div class="right-content">[img]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah great yes! This is going in the very right direction!
Only issue is that the img doesn't take 33% of the window's width anymore. But your solution was the inspiration I needed to find a solution that fits my use case. I'll post it below!

Comment: @Daniel Ah, you want 33% of the window .. then simply remove the width I defined

Comment: Thanks! But what I needed is that the image has 33% width and goes all the way to the edge of the window, while the text grows from the left of the top container to the very start of the image. Check my answer to see what I mean :)

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you get rid of `.item-end` and `.item-start` divs so you can easily control the content.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
    position:relative;
    max-width:360px;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

.different-width {
    max-width:450px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.content-center {
  justify-content:center;
}

.top {
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato
}

.left-content,
.right-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.width-2-3 {
  width: 66.666%;
}

.width-1-3 {
  width: 33.3333%
}

.left-content {
  max-width: 240px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
}

.right-content {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="col items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row content-center">
  <div class="container different-width">
    <div class="left-content width-1-3">text</div>
    <div class="right-content width-2-3">[img]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to have more control over the `left-content` and `right-content` width, consider using `flex-grow` and `flex-basis`.

If you want to control the width of the second `container`, make another class with a different `max-width` value.